# How to convert FoxPro data into SQL Server and keep the data type right?

Tags: sql-server, database, foxpro

I am importing FoxPro database to SQL server. I used MS SQL Server FoxPro Import, Export & Convert Software to convert and import the data into my SQL Server. It succeeded, but the data type of each column has changed to varchar(8000). Is there any better method to import FoxPro Database into SQL server and keep the data type of the imported data right?

Comment: What should the data type be?  Is varchar(8000) too large or not large enough?  And what version of SQL Server?

Comment: The problem is that it changes all the data types to varchar. e.g. it changes the '22/092015' of date in foxpro to '22/9/2015' of varchar in sql server. I am using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Use the [Sql Server upsizing wizard](https://vfpx.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Sedna&referringTitle=Home#SQLServerUpsizing) instead. This will convert the columns correctly, see http://www.codemag.com/article/0703052

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I don't find a direct solution for the problem. Here is my work-around.

1. Import all the data from foxpro to sql server.
2. Create one more set of tables (with new names)
3. Copy and cast the data from old tables to new tables, something like: INSERT INTO  SELECT CAST(col as your wanted data type) FROM

Comment: Another workaround: import the database from foxpro to MS Access first and then import from MS Access to SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try [DBF Commander Pro](http://dbf-software.com)'s [Export to DBMS](http://dbf-software.com/dbf-file.html#ImpExpDBMS) feature. It converts field type during the export process. Choose '*Create new table*' item as a destination table:

[image: export dbf to database]